CORS Error in connecting Babylon.js and Colyseus server
error screenshot I am getting a CORS error when I'm trying to connect to colyseus server. I have provided code pls check what is the issue.
Server file - index.js
// server/index.js
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'colyseus';
import GameRoom from './rooms/GameRoom.js';
import { matchMaker } from "@colyseus/core";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 2567;

// CORS middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(204); // No Content
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

// Configure CORS headers
matchMaker.controller.getCorsHeaders = function (req) {
    return {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  // Allow all origins
      'Vary': '*',                         // Vary by all headers (or specify specific ones if needed)
      // Other headers can be added here if needed
    };
  };


// Create HTTP & WebSocket servers
const server = http.createServer(app);
const gameServer = new Server({
    server
});



This is the server's index file , here too i added cors settings
Client file - colyseusclient.js
import * as Colyseus from "colyseus.js";


// Extend Colyseus client to set withCredentials
class CustomClient extends Colyseus.Client {
    constructor(url) {
        super(url);
    }

    createRequest(route, method = "GET", options = {}) {
        options.credentials = 'include';  // Enable sending credentials with each request.
        return fetch(route, options);
    }
}

const client = new CustomClient("ws://localhost:2567");
console.log("client object" ,client)

let room;

fetch("http://localhost:2567/", {
    credentials: "include"
})
.then(response => console.log("Server Response:", response))
.catch(error => console.error("Connection error:", error));

export async function connectToRoom() {
    try {
        room = await client.joinOrCreate("game_room"); => error is here


i tried adding all cors in request and response what i could

can you share what the error was?

@user11877521 added a link above only , pls check

You are setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to http://localhost:3000 in your Express middleware but using a wildcard (*) in the matchMaker.controller.getCorsHeaders function. When Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to true, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header cannot be a wildcard.
It should work if you replace
matchMaker.controller.getCorsHeaders = function (req) {
    return {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  // Allow all origins
      'Vary': '*',                         // Vary by all headers (or specify specific ones if needed)
      // Other headers can be added here if needed
    };
  };

With the below code:
// Configure CORS headers for Colyseus matchmaker
matchMaker.controller.getCorsHeaders = function (req) {
    return {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',  // Match the allowed origin
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',               // Allow credentials
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    };
};


did the above change , still showing the same error
